# autocomplete (категории)

Tags: php, jquery

Доброго времени суток всем, сделал автокомплит с выводом категорий так как сдесь http://jqueryui.com/...ete/#categories

Проблема в том что оно выводит все категории независимо ключевое слово какой категории вводится.

**Как сделать что бы выводилась в автокомплите та категория которую вводишь? как на примере, в зависимости от того какое слово воодишь та категория и высвечивается**

```
//search_bibl.php
     function search_autocomplete(){

            global $connection;
        $search = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['term']));
     $query = "SELECT * FROM kard WHERE author LIKE '%{$search}%' OR add_authors LIKE '%{$search}%'  
                    OR inv_number LIKE '%{$search}%' OR name_vudannya LIKE '%{$search}%' GROUP BY inv_number LIMIT 10";
                    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    $result_search= array();
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

                    $result_search[] = array(
                    'label' => $row['author'], 'category' => 'автор'

                    );     

                    $result_search[] = array(
                    'label' => $row['name_vudannya'], 'category' => 'книга'
                        );     

                        $result_search[] = array(
                    'label' => $row['inv_number'], 'category' => 'инвертарный номер'
                        );  
                }
                return $result_search;
                }


index.php
    <script>
                $(function(){

                    $('.qwerty:eq(0)')
                        .keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty' })
                    $(".qwerty").catcomplete({
                        source: '<?=PATH?>function/search_bibl.php',
                        minLength: 2,
                        select: function( event, ui){
                        window.location ='<?=PATH?>shablon/basic_bibl.php?search=' + encodeURIComponent(ui.item.value);
                        }
                    })
                .addAutocomplete()
                .addTyping();
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что переменная `$query` должна содержать:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM kard WHERE author LIKE '".
  $search."%' OR add_authors LIKE '".
  $search."%' OR inv_number LIKE '".
  $search."%' OR name_vudannya LIKE '".
  $search."%' GROUP BY inv_number LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: ничего не поменялось, те же результаты выдает